# Do College Cafeterias Put Laxatives in Their Food?

Tags: nutrition, nutritional-supplements, university

Going into college this fall, I've heard various rumors about this. Some first hand from college students, some from people who spoke to college students, and some just rumors.

The idea is: sick kids are expensive, kids that crap a lot don't get sick as often, food that naturally is good for digestion is expensive, laxatives are cheap, **therefore** laxatives should be put in the food.

What do you guys think? Is there any solid evidence of this happening at a college? A quick google yields lots of results but it's hard to sift fact from fiction.

EDIT: Per request, here are a couple examples. Most discredit this myth without any hard evidence.

http://www.snopes.com/college/admin/laxative.asp#xYspOx7LXMY2GYbg.99
"Many students do notice once they're living on campus that their bathroom habits change — they find themselves having to go more frequently, and note that their output is greater in volume."

http://www.youniversitytv.com/news-edgy/4965-college-myths-debunked-corn-dogs-with-a-side-of-laxatives
"As delightful as your dining experience was, chances are you felt the results of that extra serving of corn a short time later as you were flooring it for the communal bathroom."

Comment: Please provide examples from Google (ideally with specifically worded claims quoted)

Comment: There seems to be no one really believing this myth. In fact, it's completely implausible. Not notable.